# How to get Edge to inline open a PDF from MVC Redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, microsoft-edge, content-disposition

I have a *Microsoft MVC 4* application that needs to open a PDF file served from another MVC application.  The code in the main application looks like this:

```
return Redirect(model.PdfUrl);
```

where model.PdfUrl looks like `http://repository.{domain_name}/pdf/whitepaper/810219c9-a599-4132-965a-d3388d0fce3e.pdf`

On the repository application, this request is routed to a controller action that looks-up the actual file from the incoming URL.  Once the physical path of the file has been found, it returns the file to the HTTP Response as follows:

```
var mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path);
return File(path, mimeType);
```

Using *Fiddler*, this creates the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/pdf
Date: Thu, 26 May 2016 16:16:07 GMT
Content-Length: 582158
```

Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer 11, all then open and render the PDF file 'inline'.  *Microsoft Edge* however, displays a prompt asking if you want to download the file - at least it does most of the time, though sometimes it just opens the file as expected/required.

I have tried adding a `content-disposition` header to the response, but it does not appear to make any difference.

```
var mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path);
var cd = new ContentDisposition
{
    Inline   = true,
    FileName = Path.GetFileName(path)
};
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString()); 
return File(path, mimeType);
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are lots of reports of others having the same issue with various versions of Edge. https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1621308/probelm-with-edge-and-contenttype-application-pdf-and-content-disposition-inline-filename-report-pdf  ...I see reports as recently as a few months ago.  Some of the problem-reporters indicate that the issue can be reproduced by using Edge to access any PDF in the browser, which I just tried and did not encounter the problem. The version I am using is: Microsoft Edge 25.10586.0.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 13.10586

Comment: I am running Microsoft Edge 25.10586.0.0, MicrosoftEdgeHTML 13.10586 too.  I have a hunch that this might be a response timing issue with Edge. Sometimes, the download prompt bar appears for just a few milliseconds and then the PDF viewer opens.  On other occasions, the download prompt bar stays open and the viewer does not appear - this inconsistent behaviour is with the same target PDF, so I am wondering if it is related to speed/latency of response.